# How can i find longest substring without number in a string of alphanumerical characters in C#

Tags: c#, string

How can i find longest substring without number in a string of alphanumerical characters in C#. for example, if a string is a1bcd2, how can i extract bcd?

Comment: Loop through it, count the length, check for previous longest substring, update, repeat ...

Comment: Shame.  You should know by now with your rep.  What have you tried?  What have you researched?  How did you get the rep you have without knowing these basic rules?

Comment: What did you tried so far? `Regex.Matches(<input>, "[A-Za-z]*").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First()` maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ like that e.g.

```
"a1bcd2".Split('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
       .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is the simplest to write solution, though it is of course not any performant, but may be good enough.

Answer (score -3):

I have wrote a function that can do that for you. I have not tested it but it should give you a rough idea.

```
 public static string GetCharOnly(string str)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return string.Empty;

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(c))
                result.Append(c);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

And you can use it like so:

```
var returnString = GetCharOnly("a1bcd2");
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question